# Provide header to the data frame with the given values

Tags: python, pandas

I need to provide header to the dataframe with given values

['IDENTIF','RIVER', 'LOCATION', 'ERECTED', 'PURPOSE', 'LENGTH', 'LANES', 
  'CLEAR-G', 'T-OR-D', 'MATERIAL', 'SPAN', 'REL-L', 'TYPE']

I have the following data in a excel in a single column.

E1,M,3,CRAFTS,HIGHWAY,?,2,N,THROUGH,WOOD,SHORT,S,WOOD
E2,A,25,CRAFTS,HIGHWAY,MEDIUM,2,N,THROUGH,WOOD,SHORT,S,WOOD
E3,A,39,CRAFTS,AQUEDUCT,?,1,N,THROUGH,WOOD,?,S,WOOD
E5,A,29,CRAFTS,HIGHWAY,MEDIUM,2,N,THROUGH,WOOD,SHORT,S,WOOD
E6,M,23,CRAFTS,HIGHWAY,?,2,N,THROUGH,WOOD,?,S,WOOD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
df = pd.read_excel("File_name.xlsx")
df = df.iloc[:,0].str.split(",", expand=True)
df.columns = ['IDENTIF','RIVER', 'LOCATION', 'ERECTED', 'PURPOSE', 'LENGTH', 'LANES', 'CLEAR-G', 'T-OR-D', 'MATERIAL', 'SPAN', 'REL-L', 'TYPE']
```